# Projected opening date of Trail Ridge Rd, Rocky Mountain National Park?

Tags: driving, national-parks, mountains, denver, colorado

I know it varies each year depending on the amount of snow, but on average around the end of May. How has the recent weather and snowfall been? Planning a trip to Denver soon so it would be great to have a rough estimate of when it will open this year. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the National Park Service can answer that. They have a webpage for [park roads](https://www.nps.gov/romo/planyourvisit/road_status.htm) including Trail Ridge Road. There is a recorded status message: *Trail Ridge Road Status Line: 970 586-1222* and other contact information.

Comment: The recorded status message just says it will open "weather permitting, late May"

Comment: [The snowpack this year is about average](https://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/ftpref/states/co/charts/basinplotsprb21.gif?)